# Kornshell and sed explanation needed

Tags: awk, sed, ksh

I have the code below. I am trying to understand what the value of the output variable myfilename will look like. An explanation what the code is doing will be appreciated. I understand the sed part as well as the substitution. 
Thanks in Advnace

```
    1=Station
    2=Entry
    4=40

    myfilename=$(filelist $1 $2 -oPQD -oPQB -oPQL -b5200 -b5200 -i$4 | sed 2d | sed 's/.*\\//' | sed 's/.*\///' | awk '{print $MK}')
```

Comment: Can you have variable names that are just numbers in Korn shell?

Comment: The value of `myfilename` depends greatly on whatever the command `filelist` outputs. Post that if you'd like help.

Answer (score 2):

***Explanation:*** since OP haven't shown samples so only going for explanation here. Here is brief explanation:

1st sed is deleting 2nd line, 2nd sed is deleting everything from starting to fill last occurrence of `\` then 3rd sed is doing the samething(though not sure what's the need of it, since sed previous to this one will take care of substitution) then finally awk is printing field of value of variable MK(again here neither MK variable us defined nor its receiving it from any other command)

Comment: Yeah, the awk bit just prints everything because `MK` isn't predefined.